# find cell, make active cell and repeat

Tags: vba, excel

I have this simple code to run on startup, it works fine except I need it to make the current founded cell with the "true" statement the `ActiveCell` and run the "Call" on that `ActiveCell` , and then move to the next "true" find and make that the `ActiveCell` and repeat the process.

```
For Each c In sheet1.Range("AU5:AU1000")     
    If c.value = True Then     
        Call startup.VALUES    
    End If    
Next c
```

problem is it finds all the "true" values , but repeat the process on current `ActiveCell`

Comment: where does your code reside? is it in some event handler or in a standard module?

Comment: Please share also your other module `startup.VALUES` . Are they in the same module ? does one of them reside in a worksheet module ?

Comment: if you can help  with this I will do the rest :For Each c In sheet1.Range("AU5:AU1000")     
    If c.value = True Then     
       'something here that will offset cell next  to "true" and lets say put a value of "1" in there 
    End If    
Next c

Comment: or some new code to find and select cell , thank you for trying

Comment: where does your code reside? is it in some event handler or in a standard module? What does "next" mean?

Comment: in standard module , lets say column "A" have true and false statements , how do I search for all the "true" cells and select the "true" cell one by one and do this to all the "true" cells

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to send "True"to the sub "startup" if "True" is the value of the cell?

```
Dim rng As  Range, c As Range

Set rng =  Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AU5:AU1000")

For Each c in rng
    If c.value = True Then 
     valToSend = c.value
    Call startup(valToSend)
 End If 
Next c
```

I can't test this, as I'm on my phone.